# Webpack 2 unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-2

Here's my webpack 2 config:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
        entry: "./js/app.js",
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
            publicPath: "/dist/", 
            filename: "bundle.js"
        },
        module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: { 
                presets: ['es2015'] 
              }
            }]
          },
        ],
      },
        devServer: {
             headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8000", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true" }
        }
};
```

Is there anything wrong with my webpack config? 
My output bundle does not transpile into ES2015.

Comment: Please post the full error

Answer (score -1):

This syntax works for me (also Webpack 2):

```
{
    test:    /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader:  'babel-loader',
    query:   {
        presets: [require('babel-preset-es2015')]
    }
},
```

FYI: ES2015 = ES6 ;) Babel transpiles ES6 to ES5 (standardized in 2009).